# Chrome Websocket through NGINX

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, websocket

Hi I have the following setup: virtual machine with nginx running websocket server which is proxied to my api.domain. Setup works in postman, react-native and safari but gives error from Chrome. Not that the handshake was canceled.
I am on free plan, I have Websockets enabled, also have proxied the subdomain and have a server origin certificate, here is my nginx sites-availaible/file config:

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
listen [::]:443 ssl;
server_name api.my_domain_is_here.com;
ssl_certificate /home/path_to_my_cert/certificate.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /home/path_to_my_cert/private.key;
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:30m;

location /wss/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8765;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_read_timeout 86400;
}
}
```

all extensions in chrome are deleted & working in guest/incognito modes.

From the console I get only: WebSocket connection to 'wss://api.my_domain_is_here.com/wss/' failed:
also In the network tab is written as Pending, Stalled.

I tried numerous ways to configure the nginx reverse proxy. Also tried to find the error description from chrome but with no success. I expect someone to have an answer that will allow me to connect to my websocket via chrome.
[Here is the network console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whdai.png)